# Pass array in querystring in Node.js

Tags: node.js, couchdb, cradle

I'm using Node.js with Cradle to call a CouchDB update handler. I need to pass an array in the querystring, but when I read the req.query object in CouchDB, only the first array value is available. So, for example using Cradle .update method:

```
db.update("myview/myupdate", id, {title:'sometitle',tags:['one','two']}, function }...
```

But when I check the QS value passed to CouchDB it's:

```
?title=sometitle&tags=one&tags=two
```

Then in the CouchDB update function, req.query.tags only gives me "two". I noticed that Cradle uses require("querystring") to do the "querystring.stringify", so I also tried visionmedia's require("qs") but then "qs.stringify" gives me:

```
?title=sometitle&tags[]=one&tags[]=two
```

It would seem that CouchDB wants the tags array passed as:

```
?title=sometitle&tags=["one","two"]
```

How can I build a querystring that looks like that?

Comment: Are you saying this is a bug in craddle? If so, you should open an issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use [Connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) and his query middleware.

```
npm install connect
```

```js
var connect = require('connect');

var server = connect();
server.use(connect.query());
server.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.end(JSON.stringify(req.query));
});
server.listen(3001);
```

Point your browser to http://127.0.0.1:3001/?tags=tag1&tags=tag2&tags=tag3

You will see: {"tags":["tag1","tag2","tag3"]}